# Keras LSTM input shape

Tags: keras, lstm

I am not sure whether I understand the shape of the input I should feed into the LSTM in keras. So I have the following setup:

```
    self._model = kr.models.Sequential()
    self._model.add(kr.layers.LSTM(100, batch_input_shape=input_shape, stateful=True, return_sequences=True))

    self._model.add(kr.layers.Dense(4))
```

The input_shape is (4,20,3) where 20 is the time step and 3 is the dimensionality of my feature vector. and 4 should be the batch size I think. Lets assume that I have a time series T and I select 4 random staring point P. so then my input to the network is constructed as follows:

```
  input = [T[p:p+20] for p in P]
```

I increase each p in P by 20 after every train_on_batch call and reset the state based on a random variable. As I understand the input has now 4 different batch each having its own distinct state. It is like training the network 4 times with different starting points.

The target labels are contained in a different time series L and it is constructed as follows:

```
  target_label = [L[p:p+20] for p in P]
```

I am getting some weird results and I wanted to make sure I get the initial idea right. So could you help to re insure me that it works as I have just described or tell me where I got it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the batch_size = 20 if you choose T[p:p+20] training instances at once?
How about trying input_shape=(20,20,3)? Could you be more specific about the result?